# Replicating download button with VBA when downloading from website

Tags: html, excel, vba, internet-explorer

I am trying to download several tables from a password protected website to which I have access and into Excel with VBA.  I can successfully download two I require but am stuck on the two below.  What I would like in both is a VBA command to submit/click the ‘download button’ which would open the file in Excel.

```
Sub b1()
    
    Dim url As String
    
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    url = "https://www.horseracebase.com/index.php"
    
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .navigate url
        Do Until .readyState = 4
            DoEvents
        Loop
        .document.all.Item("Login").Value = "HRBSolly"
        .document.all.Item("Password").Value = "NarulaFlorence181019"
        .document.forms(4).submit
    End With
    
    url = "https://www.horseracebase.com/dailytrainers.php"
    
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .navigate url
        
        Do Until .readyState = 4
            DoEvents
        Loop
       
        .document.forms(4).submit
    End With
    
End Sub

Sub b2()

    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    url = "https://www.horseracebase.com/horsebaseratings.php"
    
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .navigate url
        
        Do Until .readyState = 4
            DoEvents
        Loop
       
        .document.forms(5).submit
    End With
    
End Sub
```

```html
<table border=1><form action='excelresults.php' method='post'>
<tr><td>Include N/R <input type=checkbox name=includenr value=1><br>
<input type=hidden name='user' value=28321><input type=hidden name='racedate' value='2020-8-19'>
<input type=submit class='downloadbutton' value='XLS'></form></td>
<td><form action='excelresults.php' method='post'><input type=hidden name='csv' value=1>
Include N/R <input type=checkbox name=includenr value=1><br>
<input type=hidden name='user' value=28321><input type=hidden name='racedate' value='2020-8-19'>
<input type=submit class='csvbutton' value='CSV'></form></td></tr></table>


<a href=horsebaseratings.php>Start Again</a><br><br>
<table border=1><tr><td>
<p class=instruction13>Criteria in use. <b>Ratings Set - VDW</b></p><table border=1 bgcolor=cornsilk><tr><th class=instruction6>Rank</th></tr></table><table border=1 bgcolor=cornsilk><tr><td class=instruction6><b>Clear Top</b></td></tr></table></td><td valign=top>
<table border=1><tr><th class=breakdown122 colspan=2>Download</th></tr>
<tr><td title='Download to excel'><form action='horsebaseratingsexcel.php' method='post'><input type=hidden name=ratingspointsclear1 value=0>
<input type=hidden name=ratingspointsclear2 value=300><input type=hidden name=usecustomsettings   value=128830>
<input type=hidden name=ratingsfromtop1 value=0><input type=hidden name=ratingsfromtop2 value=300>
<input type=hidden name=ratingsrankget value='100'>
<input type=hidden name=hcaptype value=1><input type=hidden name=formtype value=1><input type=hidden name='user' value=28321><input type=hidden name=tod value=1>
<input type=submit class='downloadbutton' value='XLS'></form></td>
```

Any suggestions/help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't provide personal login details in the question and also can you indicate which element within html needs to be clicked.

Comment: `ie.navigate https://www.horseracebase.com/excelresults.php` might initiate download.

Comment: Or try ie.document.querySelector("form .downloadbutton").click

Comment: Does the table in an iframe? Have you set the right numbers to the `forms()`? Besides, I think you can try QHarr's suggestions. `ie.navigate https://www.horseracebase.com/excelresults.php` and `ie.navigate https://www.horseracebase.com/horsebaseratingsexcel.php` will submit the forms and may initiate downloads. Or you can try `ie.document.getElementsByClassName("downloadbutton")(x).Click`. You need to set a number to `x` to find the downloadbutton.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  I posted login details in error, I was editing my question and posted before deleting.  I have changed my login details, and now sorted - above worked - thanks all.

Comment: @Solly From your last comment, it seems that you have solved the issue. You can post the solution for this issue as an answer and mark it as an accepted answer. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Apologies for not closing this subject.  I solved it by changing .form numbers (each page was a different number), and oddly by running each download request from a separate macro, which then worked. Thanks for the help